# How to detect ignored large file on input file with Safari mobile

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mobile-safari, file-io

Safari mobile `<input type="file">` ignore large files that are passed in (Currently testing with [a 10mb image file](http://www.rhysy.net/Timeline/LargeTimeline.png)).

When it does so, the input doesn't trigger any events (no change, no error, nothing). It just ignore the user action.

Is there anyway to detect when this happen in order to notify our user?

Test case here: http://jsbin.com/hugeja/8/edit

---

**Edit**: As this really looks like a 
Safari but, I opened issue #16862230 on the Safari bug tracker (I'd leave a link but there's none... oh Apple...) Please go comment on this issue if you can reproduce!

Answer (score 0):

I found an article on iFadey about calculating the size of an uploaded file: http://www.ifadey.com/2012/05/get-file-size-from-input-control/

This is the JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var inputImg = document.getElementById( 'inputImg' );

    inputImg.addEventListener( 'change', function( e ) {
        var fileSize = getFileSize( inputImg );

        if( fileSize > -1 ) {
            document.getElementById( 'fileSize' ).innerHTML = ( fileSize / 1024 ).toFixed( 2 ) + ' KB';
}
        else
            document.getElementById( 'fileSize' ).innerHTML = 'Failed to get file size';
    }, false );
}, false );

function getFileSize( inputFile ) {
    var files = inputFile.files;

    if( !files ) {
        //for IE
        try {
            var fs = new ActiveXObject( 'Scripting.FileSystemObject' );
            var file = fs.getFile( inputFile.value );
            return file.size;
        } catch( ex ) {
            return -1;
        }

    } else if( files.length > 0 ) {
        //for rest of the world
        return files[ 0 ].size;
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll only need the `files.length > 0` part of the code, as you are targeting Safari(not IE), but I posted the entire code anyway.
After adding this script, I was able to upload a 13 MB video on my iPhone Safari. It was being compressed automatically, but the script still returned the actual file size.

Have a look here: http://jsbin.com/kubodoqe/3/edit

Try it out and let me know if it works.

**EDIT:** If you want to set the max size of the uploaded file to 10 MB, add this to the code:

```
    if(fileSize > 10485760) {
alert("Your file is too large to be uploaded");
inputImg.value = "";
document.getElementById( 'fileSize' ).innerHTML = "";
}
```

Updated JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/kubodoqe/5/edit

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a method to notify the user if the file exceeds 10 MB (you can change that to any value - it's in bytes). However, it seems to be uploading properly even when I added the code to check the file size. Try it yourself and let me know if it works. Cheers!

Comment: I tested your jsBin on iOS and it doesn't work for me. The only difference I can see, is that I tried to upload a 10mo jpeg file and not a video. So Safari may handle file types differently. Try it out with an image. For example: http://www.rhysy.net/Timeline/LargeTimeline.png